# How to change image to an MKAnnotation with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, annotations

I have a map with 2 annotations and I want 2 different images to each of them.

I know how to do it with one annotation, but my problem is with two annotations.

Here is my code for one:

```
 func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        let reuseId = "pin"

        var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)


        anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        anView!.image = nil;
        anView!.image = UIImage(named:"destinationPin")


        return anView

    }
```

And If anyone can I'd really appreciate if you explain me what is reuseId.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean two annotations? Two separate classes?

Comment: I have two pins on my map and i want each of them to have a different image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when adding the annotations to the map, you'll need to differentiate between them. The easy way is to set the tag value. Then you can branch you logic as follows:

```
if annotation.tag == 0 {
    anView!.image = UIImage(named:"destinationPin")
} else {
    anView!.image = UIImage(named:"alternateDestinationPin")
}
```

Note MKAnnotation has other properties like title and coordinate that can be used to branch your logic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i will check it asap and let you know

Comment: I used title. I assume you put tag as something general right? (because it returned me an error that annotation doesn't have member tag)

Comment: Yes. In my current project I am subclassing like adasdadas suggested and had added a tag value. I forgot I did that when I posted the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can cast them as Optionals.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let reuseId = "pin"

    var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)

    if let annotation1 = anView as? FirstAnnotation {
        annotation1.image = UIImage(named: "first.jpg")
    } else if let annotation2 = anView as? SecondAnnotation {
        annotation2.image = UIImage(named: "second.jpg")
    }
    return anView
}
```

This has the added benefit of type-safety and not relying on your own knowledge of what's lying inside a `tag`. If you have two separate `MKAnnotation` types, you should really sub-class them as two individual classes.